# LDAP Auth for Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, ldap

I've followed the instructions at https://github.com/strebl/ldap-auth with  a brand new laravel project and I can't seem to get it to work. I have done the following:

Added the following line to app.php

```
Ccovey\LdapAuth\LdapAuthServiceProvider::class
```

Changed the driver to LDAP in auth.php

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'ldap',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ]
    ],
```

I've also created a adladap.php file that I haven't posted here.

I have also added middleware group in order to make sure the user was authenticated.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/test', function(){ return "Test";});
}
```

However when I try to go to the test route I get the following error

```
InvalidArgumentException in CreatesUserProviders.php line 40:
Authentication user provider [ldap] is not defined.
```

I'm sure there's some simple configuration that I've been looking over but  for the life of me I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Have you already tried https://packagist.org/packages/aparticka/laravel-auth-ldap? Since it is written for laravel5 it might be the better package to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do *adminless* LDAP, this might be of interest:

[laravel-simple-ldap-auth](https://github.com/jotaelesalinas/laravel-simple-ldap-auth)